# Pandas creates a new column each time I save a dataframe as csv in Python

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I am buffled with the following behavior of Pandas:  A new column is added each time I save a dataframe as a csv file.

For a reproducible example:

```
print(df)
Medical_Keyword_17  Product_Info_2_A5  Medical_History_27  Family_Hist_2
1                   0                  0                   3            0.0
2                   0                  0                   3            0.0
3                   0                  0                   3            0.0
4                   0                  0                   3            0.0
5                   0                  0                   3            0.0
6                   0                  0                   3            0.0
7                   0                  1                   3            NaN
8                   0                  0                   3            0.0
9                   0                  0                   3            0.0

df.to_csv('toy_data.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('toy_data.csv')
print(df1)
Unnamed: 0  Medical_Keyword_17  Product_Info_2_A5  Medical_History_27  \
0           1                   0                  0                   3   
1           2                   0                  0                   3   
2           3                   0                  0                   3   
3           4                   0                  0                   3   
4           5                   0                  0                   3   
5           6                   0                  0                   3   
6           7                   0                  1                   3   
7           8                   0                  0                   3   
8           9                   0                  0                   3   

   Family_Hist_2  
0            0.0  
1            0.0  
2            0.0  
3            0.0  
4            0.0  
5            0.0  
6            NaN  
7            0.0  
8            0.0
```

How can I understand this behavior and avoid it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This first column is called `index`.

For avoid write it to `file` use `index=False`:

```
df.to_csv('toy_data.csv', index=False)

df1 = pd.read_csv('toy_data.csv')
```

Or use `index_col` parameter in `read_csv`:

```
df.to_csv('toy_data.csv')

df1 = pd.read_csv('toy_data.csv', index_col=[0])
```